How to solve this matrix equality problem.
Think of a matrix $A$ and $B$ such that $A\cdot B = C$ where $A$ is of order $2\times2$ and $B$ is of order $2\times1$ and $C$ as you Know of order $2\times1$, The problem arises when I try to impose some elementary operation to both sides of the equality. As on right side we can apply any elementary operation on matrix $C$. But when I have to apply that same operation on left side, I got $2$ options to apply it on i.e. matrix $A$ and $B$ but this operation should be applied to $A$ matrix only if I do it on $B$ matrix, it will be wrong. Help me out please.

Welcome to MSE!  As you are a new contributor to the site. I suggest you read some basic information about writing mathematics at this site, see, e.g. How can I format mathematics, There should be universal LaTeX/MathJax guide for sites supporting it, and MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference

Think of an elementary operation like "add 3 times the first coordinate to the second", so that
$$\pmatrix{a\\b}
$$becomes
$$\pmatrix{a\\b+3a}.
$$
Doing this can be effected by multiplying on the left by the matrix
$$
U = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 
3 & 1}.
$$
Try it...you'll see. So if we want to apply this operation to both sides of your equation, we end up with
$$
U(AB) = UC.
$$
Because matrix multiplication is associative, that's the same as
$$
(UA)B = UC
$$
So "add three times first row to second" should be done to both $C$ and to $A$, but not to $B$, to make the new equation just as true as the old one. For instance, suppose that you have $AB = C$ with the actual values
$$
\pmatrix{3 & 1 \\2 & 0} \pmatrix{1 \\ 4} = \pmatrix{7\\2}
$$
You can check by multiplying out that this is an equality. Now let's do a row-operation, and subtract the 2nd coordinate from the first. The $U$ matrix in that case is
$$
U = \pmatrix{1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1}
$$
and our equation becomes
$$
\pmatrix{1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1} \left(\pmatrix{3 & 1 \\2 & 0} \pmatrix{1 \\ 4}\right) = \pmatrix{1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1}
\pmatrix{7\\2}
$$
which I regroup to
$$
\left(\pmatrix{1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1} \pmatrix{3 & 1 \\2 & 0}\right) \pmatrix{1 \\ 4} = \pmatrix{1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1}
\pmatrix{7\\2}
$$
Multiplying out a bit, this gets me
$$
\pmatrix{1 & 1 \\2 & 0} \pmatrix{1 \\ 4} = 
\pmatrix{5\\2}
$$
which is (as you can check) once again a valid equality.

You are correct but can you please bother to try this matrix equation and perform this same procedure please:::   consider (1     2   )  *(1     1  in row 1 and 1    1 in row 2) = (3     3)    please apologize me as i don't know how to write it exactly.!!

Please let me know if you can do it tomorrow is my exam please clarify me soon!

(a) I don't actually understand what you're asking for and (b) I'm a bit busy today, so I probably don't have time to deal with this. Sorry.
